# List of Figures in Enterprise Architect Generate Documentation

Tags: documentation, enterprise-architect

I am working on generate documentation option of Enterprise Architect. I am able to get figures labelled in the document by setting the following in template:
Figure :{Diagram.Figure}:{Diagram.Name} and setting it as a caption text.

I want to add a List of Figures for the same in template below the table of contents option. There is an option called "Table of Figures" but I am not able to understand how to use it in template.

kindly help in setting template contents for generating List of Figures in the generated document.

[image: Table of figures option]

Comment: I have updated the question ..please check it.

Comment: Where exactly do you see the option "Table of Figures"? We use post processing in MS Word to add table of figures.

Comment: I have added image..please check it

Comment: That is not an option to insert a table of figures, but a paragraph/character style

Comment: Okay..when I try to add list of figures in MS Word through References->Insert Table of Figures, I am getting No table of figures found message

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for table of figures in EA.

What you can do is make sure all your images (or even better the captions under the images) have the same "caption" style.

Then you can create a table of figures based on the style of the captions in Word.